# Declaring a static array in VBA class

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to declare a static array inside **Budget class**:

```
private Static budgets(1 To MAX_BUDGETS_AMOUNT) As Budget
```

I want it in order to have a "ready for action" array of already instantiated objects of the same class.

Vba gives me this syntax error while highlighting "budgets" with blue:

> Compile error: Expected: Sub or Function or Property

Is it allowed to have a static array inside VBA class? If yes then how should I implement it?
Thanks.

Comment: ```Static``` keyword can be used with ```Sub, Function, Property Let/Get/Set``` and at procedure level to declare variables. So it is not possible to have ```static array``` in a class directly. For more info about ```static``` see [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251391.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Help is quite clear. Static must be declared at procedure level.

I think you just want a module level variable. Use the Class Initialise function to fill it.

If Max_Budget is a variable it won't work. If it's a Const it will. There is no maths or expression evaluation done when declaring variables.

Comment: Will the static variable inside class method be alive and available to other methods in the same class?

Comment: No it won't. You don't need or want a static variable. You need a normal module level variable declared with DIM. While your class exists it won't lose it's data.

Answer (score 1):

I use this for my VBA script:

```
 Const AVALUES = "1:10:5" 
Public A(2) As Integer 

Public Sub MyMacro() 
    Dim vntTemp As Variant 
    Dim intIndex As Integer 
    vntTemp = Split(AVALUES, ":") 

    For intIndex = 0 To 2 
        A(intIndex) = vntTemp(intIndex) 
    Next 

    Debug.Print A(0) 
    Debug.Print A(1) 
    Debug.Print A(2) 
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please explain how it relates to my question? You declare an array but my problem was to make a static array in a class module...